# jQuery: Grab element and only apply to its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know the title is confusing but I wasn't sure how to phrase it.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/xnem879m/1/

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** 
When I click on the `h3` element in each container, it turns into an "x" and lengthens the container and when I click on it again, it reverts back to its text and height.

However, my problem is if you click on another container after the initial one, it will grab that `h3` element and apply it to the rest of the containers.

To reciprocate this problem, do this:
1.) Click on the first container
2.) Click on the second container 
3.) Now click on the first container which will revert to its original height but now it has the second container's `h3` element.

I see that my problem is that my first function is grabbing the `h3` element but I'm really not sure how to fix this issue.

```js
$("h3").one("click", function(){
window.h3title=$(this).text(); //Make global variable so next function has access to it.
console.log(h3title);

});

$("h3").click(function(){

if( $(this).parents(".work").height()<200){
 $(this).stop().parents(".work").animate({height: '300px'}, {duration:500, complete:function(){
 $(this).find('h3').text('X');
 
 }
 });
 
 }//IF
 else{
  $(this).stop().parents(".work").animate({height: '100px'}, {duration:500, complete:function(){
  $(this).find('h3').text(h3title);
 
 }
 });
 
 }

  
  });
```

```css
.work{
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
h3{
  color:red;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
  cursor:pointer;
}
span{
  color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work">
  <h3>1 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3>2 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3>3 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3>4 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3>5 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
```

Comment: problem in setting the global.check your console you override the previous value of the global var the you will be setting on the h3. i suggest you save in localstorage the h3 value and the h3 index to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just have 2 h3s per container. The 'x' is hidden in the beginning. When the title is clicked, show the x, and hide the title. Toggle when someone clicks on the 'x' again. There is multiple ways to do this, but the problem is your 'h3title' global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the global variable you're declaring (and it doesn't have to be global. All it has to do is be declared in a scope that's a parent to both function scopes.) is getting overwritten on every call, and every element that has access to it will use the last value it was set to.

E.g.

1. Store '1 Click me' in variable
2. Store '2 Click me' in variable
3. Restore text to first `h3`, which is now '2 Click me'.

The solution is to store the data in a context specific place. Since it's consistent, you can assign a `data-index` (or whatever you want to name it) to the element.

```js
$("h3").click(function() {

  if ($(this).parents(".work").height() < 200) {
    $(this).stop().parents(".work").animate({
      height: '300px'
    }, {
      duration: 500,
      complete: function() {
        $(this).find('h3').text('X');

      }
    });

  } //IF
  else {
    $(this).stop().parents(".work").animate({
      height: '100px'
    }, {
      duration: 500,
      complete: function() {
        var $h3 = $(this).find('h3');
        $h3.text($h3.attr('data-index') + ' Click me');

      }
    });

  }


});
```

```css
.work {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
h3 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="work">
  <h3 data-index="1">1 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3 data-index="2">2 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3 data-index="3">3 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3 data-index="4">4 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
<div class="work">
  <h3 data-index="5">5 Click me</h3>
  <span>I will Change</span>
</div>
```